# Email template issue

Tags: form, emails, plugin-contactformextensions

I'm using [Rias500/craft-contact-form-extensions](https://github.com/Rias500/craft-contact-form-extensions) plugin for creating custom email confirmation templates, and it works great but when I try to override the template (because I need confirmation emails per form) in my form with (which is the example in the documentation):

`<input type="hidden" name="message[template]" value="{{ 'contact'|hash }}">`

It will still send the email in the template I set in my CP. Am I doing something wrong?

If anyone knows another good solution for this then I like to hear it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use craft plugin design by [pixel & tonic](https://plugins.craftcms.com/contact-form) as they are the best support with Craft CMS 2 and 3.